# How to "dominate" enemy heroes

Tags: dota-2

On one of the pub games i had where Aiushtha (Enchantress) was on my team, we had this one mid-game clash where enemy Pudge's hp turned green and became invulnerable, clearly suggesting he got dominated (like that helm-of-dominator type of domination), no, my mind tricked me not, that's for sure. Well off course Echantress has this amazing eponymous skill (where she could dominate even illus, if my mem'ry serves me right), but the description strictly says that if the target is a hero, it would slow the target instead. Is this some sort of bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used on an enemy hero, Enchantress' Enchant slows. However, Enchantress can dominate illusions of enemy heroes. Pudge had most likely activated an illusion rune and Enchantress used Enchant, dominating the illusion.

Comment: quite unlikely, i forgot to mention that even pudge was bemused when that fuss happened. Anyways, is it really impossible to directly dominate any hero?

Comment: @whitehat I'm just a casual player of DotA and DotA2, but I never saw an enemy hero got dominated (as in, "controlled") by ally, unless it's changed recently, or really a bug. While I haven't encountered the case on this answer, it seems very likely. OTOH, the pudge might be acting, or he might be well surprised that an illusion could be dominated.

Comment: No you can't take control of an enemy hero.